# reading a multi-indexed CSV in pandas with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a very human-readable script that will be multi-indexed. It looks like this:

```
A
    one    : some data
    two    : some other data

B
    one    : foo
    three  : bar
```

I'd like to use pandas' `read_csv` to automatically read this in as a multi-indexed file with both `\t` and `:` used as delimiters so that I can easily slice by section (i.e., A and B). I understand something like that `header=[0,1]` and perhaps `tupleize_cols` may be used to this end, but I can't get that far since it doesn't seem to want to read both the tabs and colons properly. If I use `sep='[\t:]'`, it consumes the leading tabs. If I don't use the regexp and read with `sep='\t'`, it gets the tabs right, but doesn't handle the colons. Is this possible using `read_csv`? I could do it line by line, but there must be an easier way :)

This is the output I had in mind. I added labels to the indices and column, which could hopefully be applied when reading it in:

```
                  value      
index_1   index_2
A         one     some data
          two     some other data
B         one     foo
          three   bar
```

EDIT: I used part of Ben.T's answer to get what I needed. I'm not in love with my solution since I'm writing to a temp file, but it does work:

```
with open('temp.csv','w') as outfile:
    for line in open(reader.filename,'r'):
        if line[0] != '\t' or not line.strip():
            index1 = line.split('\n')[0]
        else:
            outfile.write(index1+':'+re.sub('[\t]+','',line))

pd.read_csv('temp.csv', sep=':', header=None, \
    names = ['index_1', 'index_2', 'Value'] ).set_index(['index_1', 'index_2'])
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: Ah yes, I should've done that - thanks! I added a sample output section to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two delimiters in read_csv such as:

```
pd.read_csv( path_file, sep=':|\t', engine='python')
```

Note the `engine='python'` to prevent a warning.

EDIT: with your input format it seems difficult, but with input like:

```
A   one    : some data
A   two    : some other data
B   one    : foo
B   three  : bar
```

with a `\t` as delimiter after A or B, then you get a multiindex by:

```
pd.read_csv(path_file, sep=':|\t', header = None, engine='python', names = ['index_1', 'index_2', 'Value'] ).set_index(['index_1', 'index_2'])
```